# Adding a condition in the standard SpaCy tokenizer

Tags: python, nlp, tokenize, spacy-3

I would like to keep the tokenizer that SpaCy normally uses, but adding a condition.

SpaCy usually separates a dot (".") from a word and places it as a token. I want to keep that, except in cases where I have the abbreviation: "et al.", in this case I would like to return as tokens: ['et' , 'al.'], without considering the dot as another token, just in this case.

I have been reviewing the information and it seems to me that the solution would be related to the script below, however, I do not know where I could place this condition.

```
import spacy
from spacy.lang.char_classes import ALPHA_LOWER, ALPHA_UPPER, PUNCT
from spacy.lang.char_classes import LIST_PUNCT, LIST_ELLIPSES, LIST_QUOTES, LIST_ICONS
from spacy.lang.char_classes import CURRENCY, UNITS, ALPHA_LOWER, CONCAT_QUOTES, PUNCT, ALPHA_UPPER
from spacy.util import compile_suffix_regex

# Default tokenizer
nlp = spacy.load("pt_core_news_sm")
doc = nlp("Esse é um exemplo. Ramon et al., kcal.")
print([t.text for t in doc]) # ['Esse', 'é', 'um', 'exemplo', '.', 'Ramon', 'et', 'al', '.', ',', 'kcal', '.']

# Modify tokenizer suffix patterns

suffixes = (
LIST_PUNCT
+ LIST_ELLIPSES
+ LIST_QUOTES
+ LIST_ICONS
+ ["'s", "'S", "’s", "’S", "—", "–"]
+ [
    r"(?<=[0-9])\+",
    r"(?<=°[FfCcKk])\.",
    r"(?<=[0-9])(?:{c})".format(c=CURRENCY),
    r"(?<=[0-9])(?:{u})".format(u=UNITS),
    r"(?<=[0-9{al}{e}{p}(?:{q})])\.".format(
        al=ALPHA_LOWER, e=r"%²\-\+", q=CONCAT_QUOTES, p=PUNCT
    ),
    r"(?<=[{au}][{au}])\.".format(au=ALPHA_UPPER),
]
)

suffix_regex = compile_suffix_regex(suffixes)
nlp.tokenizer.suffix_search = suffix_regex.search
doc = nlp("Esse é um exemplo. Ramon et al., kcal.")
print([t.text for t in doc]) # Expected -> ['Esse', 'é', 'um', 'exemplo', '.', 'Ramon', 'et', 'al.', ',', 'kcal', '.']
```

Comment: The official docs have a section on customizing the tokenizer, does it not solve your problem? https://spacy.io/usage/linguistic-features#native-tokenizers

Answer (score 1):

For this instance, I think the easiest thing to do is to add a [special case](https://spacy.io/usage/linguistic-features#special-cases) to the tokenizer. The benefit is that you don't have to recreate and recompile all of those tokenizer regexes, but just add this one instance as follows:

```py
import spacy
from spacy.symbols import ORTH

nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")

nlp.tokenizer.add_special_case("al.", [{ORTH: "al."}])

# Check new tokenization
print([w.text for w in nlp("et al.")])  # ['et', 'al.']
```

It would be good to review how the tokenizer works to understand what this is going to do. The tokenizer handles special cases first, so whenever it sees this substring it's going to tokenize it that way before any of the other rules. That means this solution could include some *false positive* tokenizations, where another token precedes `al.` aside from 'et' and you don't want to combine the period. For a more precise solution, you could write a small component that merges the `al` and `.` tokens after things have been tokenized - a good example for this is spaCy's [`merge_noun_chunks`](https://spacy.io/api/pipeline-functions#merge_noun_chunks) ([source](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/blob/master/spacy/pipeline/functions.py#L15)).